# How to fix Cannot Serialize error while setting up Django 1.9 application

Tags: python, django, azure, serialization

I'm setting up a Django 1.9 app (Python 2), but am having trouble with it. When I try `python manage.py makemigrations`, I get the following error:

> ValueError: Cannot serialize: [myapp.models.OverwriteStorage object
>   at 0x7fa1b84fc150] There are some values Django cannot serialize into
>   migration files. For more, see
>   https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/migrations/#migration-serializing

OverwriteStorage is a custom class I've included in models.py that overrides Django's inbuilt Storage class (found at **django/core/files/storage.py**) with Azure Storage. Going to the link cited above gives me a listing of what all Django can't serialize before migrating.

What do you suggest I do to fix this? Please ask for more information if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your storage class must be deconstructible. The point #4 [in this checklist](https://docs.djangoproject.com/ja/1.9/howto/custom-file-storage/). It means, you need to provide a [deconstruct()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/ja/1.9/topics/migrations/#custom-deconstruct-method) method in your custom storage class

something like this:

```
def deconstruct(self):
    path = 'python to your storage class'
    args = {}
    kwargs = {}
    return path, args, kwargs
```

quote from docs:

> Your storage class must be deconstructible so it can be serialized
>   when it’s used on a field in a migration. As long as your field has
>   arguments that are themselves serializable, you can use the
>   django.utils.deconstruct.deconstructible class decorator for this
>   (that’s what Django uses on FileSystemStorage).

Comment: Thanks buddy. I actually ended up using the `@deconstructable` class decorater imported via `from django.utils.deconstruct import deconstructible`

Comment: @HassanBaig even better :)